# How can i copy the lines, or words observed the numbers of rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++

How can i copy the lines, or words observed the numbers of rows?

1 -- text

2 -- text

3 -- text

4 -- text

I want copy lines 2-4. not lines 1-3. I want maintaining the structure of lines but the lines 1-3 are blank line

1 --> blank lines

2 --> text

3 --> blank line

4 --> text

[image]

I'm using Excel or Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a hack way in Excel, but I can't think of another method at the moment.  In your given example, you could add `=A1` to cell D1 and it would reproduce the text.  Either add that reference one at a time to the cells you want to keep data, or copy to the whole column then delete the ones you want left blank.  Once you have all the proper rows showing, highlight the column, copy, and do a `Paste values`.  This will remove the formulas and replace with the actual data you wanted, leaving the structure intact.

Comment: The problem is this: when i mark lines in N++ and when i copy to clipboard the new lines are collapsed..This happens because i don't copy not marked lines. But i don't want have collapsed lines, not marked lines should be blank lines..is possible with some plugin?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anyway to get them out of N++ like that.  Not sure a plugin would work either, since the marks you're using are bookmarks, which don't actually exist in the file.  They are just temporary visual indicators for while you are using that file.

Answer (score 0):

In Office documents (Word, Excel)

- Select the whole first row, not just the cells with text, that you want to copy
- Hold the Ctrl key down and select each of the other rows you want to copy
- Right click somewhere in the selected part
- Choose Copy
- Go to where you want to paste it
- Right click in the upper left cell in Excel
- Choose Paste

Comment: That works for selecting different parts of the text, but when you paste the data it loses the spacing between them, which is something they requested to keep.

Answer (score 0):

excel formula (assuming your text is in column A:

copy into B1: `=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,A1,"")`
then copy this down column B until the end of your data